# Does Parse support bluetooth and other peripheral interfaces?

Tags: parse-platform

I understand Parse provides translation of its own api and native APIs. Do anybody know if it also supports the native APIs for peripheral access, such as bluetooth, etc? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does not. Parse only provide APIs to access their services (Data, CloudCode, Push, Analytics, etc) and Social Login through Facebook or Twitter.